# SQLiteException: no such table: (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm attempting to execute an SQL Query via android - and I am currently unable to do so. I'm getting a fatal error and the application closes when attempting to perform a simple query which I have verified to be valid: `SELECT * FROM TblMovie WHERE MovieYear = 1975`

However - when I attempt to do so within my app:

### MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

    List<String> list = dbhelper.getData();

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    textView1.setText(list.get(0));
    textView2.setText(list.get(1));
```

...

### DBHelper:

```
 public List<String> getData() {  
     db = this.getReadableDatabase();  
     List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();  
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TblMovie WHERE MovieYear = 1975", null);  
     while (c.moveToNext()) {  
         data.add(c.getString(0));  
         data.add(c.getString(1));



     }  
     c.close();  
     db.close();  
     return data;  
    }
```

### Logcat:

```
05-19 10:24:59.983: E/AndroidRuntime(24736): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TblMovie (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TblMovie WHERE MovieYear = 1975



http://pastebin.com/0mAD87jJ
```

Also - I have found this article as reference:

[No such table: (code 1) while compiling: SELECT * FROM event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878505/no-such-table-code-1-while-compiling-select-from-event)

I have tried running it on my tablet instead of the emulator - still does not work. I also tried clearing data - that does not work either. I have the database in my assets folder so I'm unsure as to why it isn't working.

### EDIT:

Why the downvote? I'm pretty sure this is a valid and not terribly written / documented / researched issue.

### DB Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwkDQ.png

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Comment: I will suggest to uninstall and install the app again.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good suggest @AAnkit, and if it doesn't worked, POST your CREATE TABLE Query.

Comment: Show you CREATE TABLE code. It seems there is an error in that instruction.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled - still crashing. I am using a precreated database in my assets folder - I do not use CREATE TABLE code :)

Comment: So, simply there is no TblMovie table in your db: `no such table: TblMovie`

Comment: use sqlite tool(in sdk/platform tools) to check tables and their structure in the database.

Comment: I suspect the OpenHelper isn't pointing to the right database, then. Can you edit with the code from `onCreate()` inside your SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM TblMovie WHERE MovieYear=?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{ String.valueOf(1975) });
```

Comment: I tried it - it resulted in SQLiteException: no such table: TblMovie (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TblMovie WHERE MovieYear=?

Comment: oh, your table is not exist.

Comment: My table does exist... it is in a database in my assets folder

Comment: ah, you have to copy this database to app before using it. You can't read database from assets folder via DatabaseHelper

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an onCreate function defined with a create script?
the following tutorial from google explains this in detail:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: I am using a precreated database in my assets folder - I do not wish to use a create script.

Comment: are you sure the capitalization is correct ? you might want to try putting " " around the tables names ?